# Birt report - count the number of times it matches a criteria

Tags: mysql, report, birt

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║id ║ TV#        ║ Time        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ TV1        ║ 0           ║
║ 2 ║ TV2        ║ 10          ║
║ 3 ║ TV3        ║ 0           ║
║ 4 ║ TV3        ║ 20          ║
║ 5 ║ TV3        ║ 21          ║
║...║ ...        ║ ...         ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to count the number of elements id, for each TV#, which time > 0.
In this case, I want the result to be:

TV1 - 0 ; TV2 - 1; TV3 - 2

I'm using BIRT Report, and I've tried different ways to get this, but I couldnt get what I want.

I've tried different ways, this is what I'm using at the moment:

**Data Cube, Summary fields (measure)**

Function: Count

Expression: measure["id"]

Filter: measure["Time"]>0

**And then I'm using an Aggregation Builder:**

Function:Count **or** Sum

Expression:measure["id"]

Filter: measure["Time"]>0

Aggregate on: GroupTV#

When I use **count**, this is returning: only 0s and 1s (it gives me "1" to TV# when there is at least one  Time>0), ie TV1 - 0 ; TV2 - 1; TV3 - 1

When I use **sum**, this is returning: the number of times each TV# appears on the table (when there is at least one  Time>0 for that channel), ie TV1 - no output ; TV2 - 1; TV3 - 3

Can someone help me?

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Comment: @Strawberry - a bit of an unfair comment as blocnt has described two things he has tried & explained how they are both failing to get the required results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using filters on Data Cube, or on Cross Tabs or on Charts, just filter on Data Sets.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT tv
     , SUM(CASE WHEN time > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY tv;
```

Comment: thanks, where that structure should be used? as a filter?

Comment: This is in relation to the mysql tag. I know nothing about Birt

Answer (score 0):

Either method should work, however in your example you're counting the occurrences of a particular id instead of 'TV#'. 
Naturally as the id's are unique there will only ever be a maximum of one occurrence of each.

You need:

Function: Count

Expression: change from 'id' to 'TV#'

Filter: measure["Time"] > 0

Comment: That isn't working. It only gives me "1" or "0" (it identifies correctly when there is a time>0, but not how many times that happen)